# Get first characters from a String

Tags: mysql

I have a string with 30 characters but i only need the 20 of them. How can i get the first 20?

I tried this substring(ltrim(rtrim(field_value)),20)

But didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What did it output? if it didn't work... Also Ian has the right idea and that may be your answer

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" what exactly do you mean. The SubString function in .Net will do the job you need.

Comment: My dummy fault was that i forgot to check from what character will begin to read.

Comment: Seems like your problem is actually for `MySQL` though you originally tag it as `C#`. Is this true? Or you actually are asking problem for `C#`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:**

In `My SQL`, you could use `LEFT` (or `SUBSTRING`) to `SELECT` certain number of characters from a `string`. Since what you need is the first characters, I suggest to use `LEFT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(field_value, 20) FROM MyTableName
```

**Original:**

*(As the tag was originally `C#`, the following solution below provides solution for `C#` problem)*

You should use `Substring(0, 20)`. The first argument (`0`) is the starting index, and the second argument (`20`) is the length of the `string` you want to take.

For example:

```
var str = "123456789012345678901234567890";
str = str.Substring(0, 20);
```

Comment: A yes, i am a little fool here. The fact is that i concerned about trim() function and forgot the starting character.
Thank you again!

Comment: @Marios Ah yes, sometimes we can miss what is obvious because of distraction. Not a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SubString method to get first 20 characters out of your string.

Try this way:

```
 str= str.Substring(0, 20);
```

Comment: Did I write something wrong here as I can't see anything wrong?

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

SELECT SUBSTR(STR,POS,LEN)