# mySQL find most common starting letter for values

Tags: mysql

**From a mySQL table I would like to determine the most frequent starting letter**; for example if the list is:

- day
- book
- cat
- dog
- apple

The expected result would ultimately allow me to determine that:

- 'd' is the most frequent starting letter
- 'd' has a count of 2

Is there a way to do this without running 26 queries, e.g.:

```
WHERE myWord LIKE 'a%' 
WHERE myWord LIKE 'b%' 
...
WHERE myWord LIKE 'y%' 
WHERE myWord LIKE 'z%'
```

**I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841580/mysql-how-to-search-for-26-records-that-each-begins-with-the-letter-of-the-alp) which makes me think I can do this in 2 steps:**

If I'm not mistaken the approach would be to first build a list of all the first letters using the approach from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343096/3451115) something like this:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(word_name, 1) as letter, word_name
> FROM word
>  GROUP BY (letter)
>  ORDER BY letter
> ```

which I expect would look something like:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- d

... and then query that list. To do this I would store that new list as a temporary table as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table), something like:

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)
> ```

and query that for Magnitude as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql), something like.

> ```
> SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
> FROM table 
> GROUP BY column 
> ORDER BY magnitude DESC
> LIMIT 1
> ```

**Is this a sensible approach?**

---

**NOTE:**

As sometimes happens, in writing this question I think I figured out a way forward, as yet I have no working code. I'll update the question later with code that either works or which needs help.

In the meanwhile I appreciate any feedback, pointers, proposed answers.

Finally, I'm using PHP, PDO, mySQL for this.

TIA

---

For what it's worth there was an easier way, this is what I ended up with thanks to both who took the time to answer:

```
$stmt_common2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as occurence,SUBSTRING(word,1,1) as letter
FROM words 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(word,1,1)
ORDER BY  occurence DESC, letter ASC 
LIMIT 1');
$stmt_common2->execute();   
$mostCommon2 = $stmt_common2->fetchAll();       
echo "most common letter: " . $mostCommon2[0]['letter'] . " occurs " . $mostCommon2[0]['occurence'] . " times)<br>";
```

Comment: What if multiple letter comes equal times?? like `x and y` comes `n` times...

Comment: @YashParekh - out of scope WRT my needs as I already know how to handle that situation, thanks

Comment: @SlowLearner please check my updated answer...

Comment: @Kirit thanks, will do - up voted both, just working through both - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by using this simple query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as occurence,SUBSTRING(word_name,1,1) as letter
FROM word 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(word_name,1,1)
ORDER BY  occurence DESC, letter ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you :-)  It was a tough choice between both answers, until one of them disappeared... Although I feel quite unqualified to accept one over the other I did find this easier to understand but both were of value.